# Running PyQGIS in FME PythonCaller transformer?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, fme-form

I am trying to get information from a QGIS project and layers and produce a new project based on new analysis results made on FME.

How to install the PyQGIS module and then using the custom python interpreter in FME Desktop?

I am using QGIS-ltr 2.18.23 (from OSGEO4w64) and FME 2018.1.0.1 (Win64).
And the python/QGIS related paths into PATH environmental variable are:
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-ltr\bin;
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27;
C:\OSGeo4W64\bin

In FME desktop I am reading the C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\python27.dll as the preferred Python interpreter
and PYHTONHOME path is: C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-ltr\python

Answer (score 2):

I believe QGIS uses/installs Python 2.7, so that's OK. FME is compatible with both 2.7 and 3 for now ([although 2.7 is being phased out](http://fme.ly/py27)).

Under Tools > FME Options > Translation set the Python interpreter to the QGIS DLL and set the Python home folder. I believe the QGIS Python dll can be found under QGIS\bin\python27.dll and the home folder is QGIS\apps\Python27

[image]

You can also set PYTHONHOME as an environment variable too. You'll also need to make sure that qgis_core.dll is included in your PATH setting as well.

Comment: I am not using those paths as i am using the osgeo4w64 install. I edited the question to give you more details on pyhtonhome and path environmental variable regarding qgis/python. So using another paths for reaching QGIS python, i am actually reaching the python27.dll interpreter and keeping qgis_core.dll in the path environmental variable. And unfortnutately, it does not work. Have you tried to load any python module from QGIS using python caller? does it work?